# Framework 7 Webpack build error exceeds the max of "500KB"

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs, html-framework-7

## Overview

I'm building a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) Seed.

## Setup

I'm using [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/), [Framework7](https://framework7.io/), [Framework7 Vue Components](https://framework7.io/vue/), with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) all transpiled with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

I started the project with the [VueJS CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) then added Framework7 and the Framework 7 Vue Components to the Webpack config.

As it states in Framework 7 [installation](https://framework7.io/docs/installation.html#es-next) Framework 7 Modules use ES-next and needs to be transpiled.

> Framework7 ES modules are in ES-next syntax, so don't forget to
> enable/configure your Babel/Buble to transpile

So I added the following to Babel Config

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    // Original: 
    // include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
    // New
    include: [
      resolve('src'),
      resolve('test'),
      resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client'),
      resolve('node_modules/framework7'),
      resolve('node_modules/framework7-vue'),
      resolve('node_modules/template7'),
      resolve('node_modules/dom7')
    ]
  },
```

## Error

When I try to run `npm run dev` I get the following

- Build Warning message

  `11% building modules 15/18 modules 3 active ...wa-seed/node_modules/events/events.js[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/mwarner/eu-pwa-seed/node_modules/framework7/dist/framework7.esm.bundle.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".`
- console of the device it shows

  "export 'default' (imported as 'PathToRegexp') was not found in 'path-to-regexp'
- Nothing is rendered on any platform iOS, Android, or Browser

I commented out the line `resolve('node_modules/framework7'),` and it works but the app does not render on anything below iOS 11 as it is not transpiling Framework 7.

Comment: It's not an error mesage, just a note about the style of your bundled app. Unless you want to read transpiled code It won't bother you, you can still use sourcemap files if you want to

Comment: good point, after looking into the console on the device itself it is not compiling correctly though I still not sure why though.

Comment: In this issue https://github.com/faceyspacey/redux-first-router/issues/79 kristfal had a similar issue and reinstalling all my npm packages resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error but just warning message says you reach the limit of 500K, but your build will still work.